# Searching for formulas?

Tags: reference-request

Is there a site to search for formulas? I often come up with formulas that I would like to know the name, where they are used or what they are related to. One would type, for example, $\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$ and it would intelligently associate it with the sum of sines formula. I know this would be no trivial service but I find it would be a great tool.

Comment: I think there was no need for me to check but anyway I just checked. Wolfram Alpha did it.

Comment: There are many lists of formulae on the internet, but if you want something which will parse what you write then you want a computer algebra system

Answer (score 4):

What about this?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: or even [this link (see "alternate form")](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+sin%28a%29*cos%28b%29%2Bsin%28b%29*cos%28a%29)

Comment: ac/(b^2-a^2) won't say it's to the closest point of a line in relation to origin - which is something I'd like to check ):

Comment: Actually, the best would probably be "What about Wolfram Alpha?" with a link attached to the words Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the existing search engines do not have that capability yet. You may check back in a year, there will be. (Trust me!)

In the meanwhile, maybe [this](http://www.knapdata.com/books/mathCompsAndFormulas.pdf) one can be of some help

Answer (score 4):

I think more specifically Dokkat is looking for http://www.jackpo.org/files/formulas.pdf (something of this sort)

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram|Alpha is the kind of thing you're looking for. For now, unfortunately, there aren't so many engines which allows you to search for *knowledge* rather than just *results*. For the sake of posting an answer though, I have heard about The Springer LaTeX search http://www.latexsearch.com/ but I'm not sure how useful could it be.

Morals of the story, you can always use a combination of Google, W|A, math.SE search bar, and question posting.

Comment: Thanks for leaving a message on my blog. You may read more there. I am anyway back and I hope I won't regret it.

Comment: @KannappanSampath I'm glad you're back!

Answer (score 0):

The [search engine at formulasheet.com](http://formulasheet.com/#q) lets you search for formulas by typing in keywords (it also provides search suggestions). It searches Wikipedia's vast array of formulas as well as user-shared formulas and a small but growing formula database of their own. It does not however provide a means to search based on the source such as sin(a)cos(b)+sin(b)cos(a) as you requested, but it does do the reverse, for example [http://formulasheet.com/#q|ev|Sine%20sum%20and%20difference%20identity](http://formulasheet.com/#q%7Cev%7CSine%20sum%20and%20difference%20identity).